# Como redirecionar o ID de um cadastro atual para impressão

Tags: php, javascript

quero redirecionar um id que vou obter somente após clicar em cadastrar, neste momento eu realizo a inserção no banco de dados em php e logo após quero redirecionar via javascript para uma página de impressão de dados que possuo, meu problema é que não tenho o dado deste id, pois acabei de cadastrar o usuário e não possuo o ID atual em alguma variável, como posso fazer para obter o dial atual que cadastrei? Ao a inserir a linha var f = "" no javascript simplesmente para de funcionar o que pode estar errado ?

Redirecionar (javascript):

```
    function dec(){
  var f = "<?php echo $ultimoID;?>"
decisao = confirm("Deseja imprimir a ficha do cliente cadastrado?");
if (decisao)
window.open('imprimir_clientes.php?id='+f, '_blank');
}
```

cadastrar banco de dados (php):

```
              <?php if (isset($_GET['cadastra']) && $_GET['cadastra'] == 'add') {
          $nascimento = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/",$_GET['nascimento'])));
            $cadastra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_cadclientes (Snome, Endereco,DataNascimento, Bairro, Cidade, Uf, Fone, Cpf, Cgc, Identidade, Pai, Mae,
                                     EstadoCivil, Cep, NomeEmpresa, EndEmpresa, BairroEmpresa, CidadeEmpresa, FoneEmpresa, Ramal, Renda,
                                     NomeConjuge,EmpresaConjuge,EndEmpresaConjuge,BairroEmpresaConjuge,CidadeEmpresaConjuge,FoneEmpresaConjuge,
                                     RamalEmpresaConjuge,RendaConjuge, NomeContato, EndContato, FoneContato,Relacao, Loja1, 
                                     Loja2, FichaDesde) 
                                    VALUES (UPPER('$_GET[nome]'), UPPER('$_GET[endereco]'), '$nascimento', UPPER('$_GET[bairro]'), UPPER('$_GET[cidade]'), '$_GET[uf]', '$_GET[telefone]',
                                     '$_GET[cpf]', '$_GET[cp]', '$_GET[identidade]', UPPER('$_GET[nomepai]'), UPPER('$_GET[nomemae]'), '$_GET[estadocivil]', '$_GET[cep]',
                                     UPPER('$_GET[nomeempresa]'), UPPER('$_GET[enderecoempresa]'), UPPER('$_GET[bairroempresa]'), UPPER('$_GET[cidadeempresa]'), '$_GET[telefoneempresa]',
                                     '$_GET[ramalempresa]', '$_GET[renda]', UPPER('$_GET[nomeconjuge]'), UPPER('$_GET[empresaconjuge]'), UPPER('$_GET[enderecoempresaconjuge]'),
                                     UPPER('$_GET[bairroempresaconjuge]'), UPPER('$_GET[cidadeempresaconjuge]'), '$_GET[foneempresaconjuge]', '$_GET[ramalconjuge]', '$_GET[rendaconjuge]',
                                     UPPER('$_GET[nomecontato]'), UPPER('$_GET[enderecocontato]'), '$_GET[telefonecontato]', UPPER('$_GET[relacaocontato]'), UPPER('$_GET[referenciacontato1]'),
                                     UPPER('$_GET[referenciacontato2]'), '$_GET[dataficha]')");
$ultimoID= mysql_insert_id();
    if($cadastra == '1') {
       // Montamos o caminho para o mesmo script:
       $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
       // Deixamos a mensagem para depois do redirect:
       $mensagem = urlencode( 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso' );
       // Redirecionamos repassando a mensagem adiante:
       header( "Location: $url?mensagem=$mensagem" );
       // E encerramos o script neste ponto:
       die();
    }else{
       echo "Erro ao cadastrar !";
    }
    }
    if ( isset( $_GET['mensagem'] ) ) {
       echo htmlentities($_GET['mensagem']);
        echo"<script>";
          echo"javascript: dec();";
        echo "</script>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Por favor, explique as alterações que fez no código da pergunta. É importante não invalidar as respostas já dadas. Se suas alterações são um feedback a resposta do Eduardo, faça um comentário avisando-o. . . . [ps] Indentar o código ajuda *muito* na leitura e localização de problemas.

Comment: Olá @brasofilo obrigado! já editei a pergunta, podes me ajudar?

Comment: @EduardoOliveira muito obrigado, editei minha pergunta inserindo o $ultimoID= mysql_insert_id(); após o insert no banco, mas quando insiro o var f - $ultimoID; o javascript para de funcionar, tens alguma ideia do que pode ser? abs

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o mysql_insert_id();

Ele pega o último ID cadastrado

```
$Codigo = mysql_insert_id();
```

Pelo que vi no seu código, após dar o INSERT, você é redirecionado para outra página... nesse caso você pode passar via URL mesmo

```
Location: $url?mensagem=$mensagem&id=$Codigo
```

Ou buscar o último ID da tabela pelo MYSQL:

```
SELECT MAX ('id') FROM 't_cadclientes'; //nesse caso estou chamando seu campo de 'id', basta colocar o nome do campo da sua tabela.
```

Esses são passos mais simples, mas você poderia criar uma session por exemplo..

```
$_SESSION['Codigo'] = $Codigo;
```

Mas para trabalhar com sessions é necessário você dar o session_start().

Comment: editei minha pergunta inserindo o $ultimoID= mysql_insert_id(); após o insert no banco, mas quando insiro o var f - $ultimoID; o javascript para de funcionar, tens alguma ideia do que pode ser? abs